# What does the context:'query' option do when using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

In a <del>failed attempt</del> learning exercise to get validators to work with 'document.update', I came across something I don't understand.

I know now that it doesn't work, but one of the things I tried was setting my options to {runValidators:true, context:'query'}. In my validator function, I tried console.logging (this), with and without the context:"query" option.

There was no difference. I received a large object (is this called the 'query object'?) This seems to go against what I read [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

> In the color validation function above, this refers to the document being validated when using document validation. However, when running update validators, the document being updated may not be in the server's memory, so by default the value of this is not defined.

It was not undefined , even without the context option.

I even tried making it an arrow function to see if the lexical this was any different. In that case, this *was* undefined, but again, changing the context option did not make a difference. (I'm still learning, so I don't know if that part is relevant).

in the model:

```
let Property = mongoose.model('Property', {
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    occupancy: {type:String},
    maxTenants: Number,
    tenants: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tenant', validate: [checkMaxTenants, "Maximum tenants exceeded for this property. Tenant not added."]}]
});
function checkMaxTenants(val){
    console.log("this",this);
    // return this.tenants.length <= this.maxTenants;
    return true;
}
```

and in the route:

```
        property.update({$set: {tenants:property.tenants}},{new:true,runValidators:true,context:'query'}, function(err,savedProperty){
```

Anything to help me better understand the discrepancy between what I think I'm reading and what I see would be great!

Answer (score 8):

At the outset, let's be clear that validators are of two types: document validators and update validators (maybe you know this already, but the snippet you posted *updates* a document, whereas the issue you mention relates to document validation upon `save`).

> There was no difference. I received a large object (is this called the 'query object'?) This seems to go against what I read here.

Document validators are run when you run `save` on documents as mentioned in the docs.

> Validation is middleware. Mongoose registers validation as a pre('save') hook on every schema by default.

Or you can call it manually with `.validate()`

> You can manually run validation using doc.validate(callback) or doc.validateSync()

Update validators are run for update operations

> In the above examples, you learned about document validation. Mongoose also supports validation for update() and findOneAndUpdate() operations.

This can be illustrated with the following snippet. For convenience I have changed the type of `tenants` to a simple integer array, but that shouldn't matter for the purpose of our discussion.

```
// "use strict";

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const assert = require('assert');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Property = mongoose.model('Property', {
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  occupancy: { type:String },
  maxTenants: Number,
  tenants: [
    {
      type: Number,
      ref: 'Tenant',
      validate: {
        validator: checkMaxTenants,
        message: "Maximum tenants exceeded for this property. Tenant not added."
      }
    }
  ]
});

function checkMaxTenants (val) {
  console.log("this", this);
  // return this.tenants.length <= this.maxTenants;
  return true;
}

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
  useMongoClient: true,
}).then(function(db) {

  const property = new Property({ name: 'foo', occupancy: 'bar', tenants: [1] });

  property.update(
    { $set: { tenants: [2, 3] } },
    {
      new: true,
      runValidators: true,
      // context: 'query'
    },
    function(err, savedProperty) {

    }
  )

  // property.save();
});
```

Above code with trigger a update validation **not document validation**

To see document validation in action uncomment `property.save()` and comment the update operation.

You'll notice that the value of this will be the `property` document.

```
this { name: 'foo',
occupancy: 'bar',
_id: 598e9d72992907120a99a367,
tenants: [ 1 ] }
```

Comment the save, uncomment back the update operation and you'll see the large object you mentioned.

Now the large object you got, you may not have realised, is the global object when you didn't set `context: 'query'` and the query object when you set the context.

This can be explained at [this line](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/817c42ed7c898009354502c666622b36687bc919/lib/services/updateValidators.js#L94) in mongoose's source. When no context was set, mongoose sets the scope to `null`. And then [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/1613ef522fb44a2870041b8833bf2f3b36fc45a0/lib/schematype.js#L818) the `.call` is called with the `scope`.

Now, in non strict mode, when `.call` is called with null, [`this` is replaced with the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). So check contents of the large object you got. When `context` is not set, it would be a global object and not the query object. You can add `"use strict";` and see that null will be logged. (The snippet posted can verify this for you). You can verify that you got a query object by running instanceof `mongoose.Query` against `this`.

Hope this helps you understand things better.

Comment: than we can't use the same validator for save and update as this value is changing in both the use cases